# Is it possible to release queue ownership of an image without knowing the layout the destination will use the image in?

Tags: vulkan

I have two queues, Queue A and Queue B, from different queue families. Queue A currently has ownership of an image in exclusive sharing mode. I want to release ownership of the image to Queue B in advance, because I know that it will be the next to use it. However, I don't know the layout Queue B will need the image to be in.

The problem is that both the releasing barrier (on Queue A) and the acquiring barrier (on Queue B) need to specify the source and destination image layouts. How can I release the image to Queue B  without knowing the layout in advance?

I would think that the best approach would be to use two image memory barriers when recording to Queue B: the first to acquire the image from Queue A (without changing the layout), and the second to perform the layout transition. The issue is that I don't know how to create a dependency to ensure that the layout transition occurs after the image is acquired. Is there a way can I create this dependency between the two sequential image memory barriers?

Comment: "*However, I don't know the layout Queue B will need the image to be in.*" Why not? What is queue B doing that nobody knows?

Comment: @NicolBolas (Don't know why it matters but...) it's because I'm translating from a rendering abstraction front end to a Vulkan backend. In this abstraction, during a frame one can specify some commands (like copying some data) to run in parallel to rendering the main frame. Because of the way the abstraction works, when those parallel commands are submitted mid-frame I know that the output (like an image) will be used in that frame. However, because the rest of the frame isn't recorded yet, (and it may be a while before it's finished recording) I don't yet know how the image will be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either queue A has to know what layout queue B wants, or queue B has to know what layout queue A is leaving the image in. That is, one of the queues has to know what layout the other one is using; they cannot both be ignorant of each other.

When you do a release/acquire pair, the destination access mask of the release is ignored and the source access mask of the destination is ignored. Essentially, the source access mask of the pair is the source access mask of the release, and the destination access mask of the pair is the destination access mask of the acquire.

As such, if you want queue B to do a layout transition after the acquire, that barrier needs to properly synchronize with the destination scope and access mask of the acquire barrier.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) I got all that, and the good new is when recording Queue B I can know what layout  the image was left in. What I'm confused about is on Queue B if I want to acquire the image and do a blit (for example), how do I set up the src/dst access masks and stages of the two barriers on Queue B before the blit to ensure the layout transition happens after the acquire?

Comment: If you know the layout that queue A is leaving the image in... then queue B is in complete control of that. The source access mask/stage for the second barrier is the same as the destination mask/stages from queue B's acquire barrier. That's just how synchronization works.

Comment: Alright cool, I was thinking that I would have to set the source mask on the second barrier to something to ensure the layout transition goes after the acquire but from what your saying I can just leave them blank? (I have a suspicion my confusion is coming from my lack of understanding of dependency chaining). Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Tacodiva: "*I can just leave them blank?*" I don't know how you got that from "is the same as". That's like the *opposite* of leaving it blank.

Comment: Sorry I'm getting confused (clearly lol). According to the specs the "srcAccessMask" of the acquire barrier is ignored, hence I was thinking to "leave it blank" like I do for the acquire barrier. But I guess that on the second barrier, while I can have an access mask of 0, I do need the stage mask to match the acquire barrier and that should work?

Comment: @Tacodiva: Oh, I see where the confusion came from. When I said "second barrier", I meant the second barrier *on queue B*, not the acquire part of the release/acquire pair. That is, the barrier that's actually changing the image's layout.

Comment: Ohhh ok I think I'm getting it now. Again thanks for all this, Vulkan is hard. So; the aquire barrier aquires the image with a destination of some intermediate stage, than the layout change barrier has a source of that intermediate stage and a destination of where the image is actually gonna get used. Does it matter that the "intermediate stage" is the same as the stage where the image will be used, or can it just be anything (maybe other than None)?